# Direct3D hook overlay

Tags: hook, overlay, render, direct3d

I am trying to achieve an effect like the program Fraps does, which is an overlay on top of a game, and to do this I am hooking the `IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene` function and rendering stuff before calling the original function. However, when I render stuff, it messes up effects that the game has already drawn, and doesn't draw itself correctly. My hook just looks like

```
HRESULT __stdcall endscene_hook(IDirect3DDevice9* id3d_device) {
    if (pGameOverlay) {
         pGameOverlay->Render();
    }

    return endscene_orig(dev);
}
```

wherer `pGameOverlay` is just a pointer to a class whose `Render` method just draws some stuff to the device it was set up with previously (not shown). Is there something else I should be doing?

I read somewhere that Fraps actually hooks the `Present` method, instead of `EndScene`. Is this correct, and if so, why? And can't you only have one `BeginScene`/`EndScene` pair in between calls to `Present`?

Comment: Just as a basic sanity check that the hooking itself is not causing the mess: when you ommit the pGameOverlay->Render(), does everything look OK?

Comment: @Suma Yep, everything renders normally when I don't render my own stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely have multiple `BeginScene/EndScene` for each Present, and it is actually quite a common practice. Usually a pair of `BeginScene/EndScene` is used for each individual Render Target. (One example of additional render target might be a mirror, but there are many other uses for multiple render targets, like shadow buffers, or dedicated depth targets for postprocess effects).

Hooking Present is a lot safer, as this is the call which actually "displays" (Presents) whatever was done to the user, and therefore from the very definition there is one Present per frame (as this is exactly this Present which defines the frame).